# + character is getting replaced by ' ' when called from ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
var data = "testStr=" + 'E+1';
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("test", "Confi", new { Area = "Confi" })',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {

            }
        });
```

Above is my ajax call. Before call `data` var has string as testStr= E+1. But when ajax call is made in controller the `+` is replaced by `blank`. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: what is &#43.? Coding for +.?

Answer (score 0):

Try using &#43 instead of +.